# Sort .bash_history content alphabetically

Tags: bash, cron

I'm using `HISTIGNORE` to ignore the most used commands and `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` to remove duplicates.

Is there a way to periodically sort the contents of the `.bash_history` in alphabetical order?

Comment: Please define ”periodically”, and where would you like to store the output; once sorted.

Comment: like once a week or something ... in => ~/.bash_history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To see a sorted history without changing it, do:

   ```
   history | sort -k2
   ```
2. To sort the history file, do:

   ```
   sort -o ~/.bash_history ~/.bash_history
   ```

   Then log out of `bash` by typing `exit`, and log back in.  The new
   terminal instance will have an alphabetically sorted history.
3. For the most cautious possible way to sort the history file, first `exit` all
   running instances of `bash`, (for the current user anyway), then do:

   ```
   sort -o ~/.bash_history ~/.bash_history
   ```

   ---

   Note:  Users generally have no bad results from editing *~/.bash_history* while still logged in.  But it's fairly certain that exiting all running instance of `bash` is as safe or safer.

Comment: This answer would be better with a `cron` job method as well, but I'm undecided on how to handle systems where terminals are left open for long periods of time.  Maybe the job could remind them to log out and log back in, but suppose that's not convenient.  Better still would be to have a method that doesn't require and `exit` at all.